# How to resolve Http 400 bad request Error in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7, webserver, http-status-code-400

We have migrated the our websites from one server to another server. all completed successfully but one website has issue of HTTP 400 bad request. I have googled alot but none of the solution works for me then I found  [this article](http://forums.iis.net/t/1168442.aspx/1) which told me to set the website under the default website in. when i do that it works for me. but i want to make the previous one working. so please help me how can i do this and please let me know why it is working under default websites.

**UPDATE:** i have also enabled the log for tracing the error but its not creating a single log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"one website has issue of HTTP 400 bad request"_ - HTTP errors are a symptom, not a cause. HTTP 400 is thrown is various situations, **you** will have to find out which one applies. Look in IIS's logs, enable tracing and check the configuration according to the framework you're using (does it have requirements regarding the app pool, the installed .NET framework and so on?).

Comment: @CodeCaster i have already tried to get the erro in logs but its not create a single log file in log folder.